# I am writing a .bat program to find and replace text in a file without changing its position

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a .bat program that will find and replace text in a file. The problem that I am having is that it is removing blank lines and left justifying the other lines. I need the blank lines to remain and the new text to remain in the same location. Here is what I have wrote, and also the result. Can anybody please help.

program:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
cd\
c:
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (samplefile.tx) do (
Set str=%%a

set str=!str:day=night!
set str=!str:winter=summer!

echo !str!>>samplefile2.txt)
ENDLOCAL
cls
exit
```

samle File:

```
this line is the first line in my file that I am using as an example.This is made up text

the cat in the hat

             day
                      winter
```

below is the result:

```
this line is the first line in my file that I am using as an example.This is made up text
the cat in the hat
night
summer
```

I need the lines, spaces and new text to remain in the same position while making the text replacement. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" q27459813.txt') DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF DEFINED line (CALL :subs) ELSE (ECHO()
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:subs
SET "line=%line:day=night%"
SET "line=%line:winter=summer%"
ECHO(%line%
GOTO :eof
```

Thi should work for you. I used a file named `q27459813.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Will not work correctly if the datafile lines start `]`.

---

Revised to allow leading `]`

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type q27459813.txt^|find /n /v "" ') DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :subs
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:subs
SET "line=%line:*]=%"
IF NOT DEFINED line ECHO(&GOTO :EOF 
SET "line=%line:day=night%"
SET "line=%line:winter=summer%"
ECHO(%line%
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Thank you all so much...i will give these a try!

Answer (score 0):

- Your use of `"tokens=* delims= "` will trim leading spaces. Instead, use `"delims="` to preserve leading spaces.
- FOR /F always skips empty lines. The trick is to insert something before each line. Typically `FIND` or `FINDSTR` is used to insert the line number at the front of each line.
- You can use `!var:*:=!` to delete the the line number prefix from FINDSTR.
- Use `echo(!str!` to prevent `ECHO is off` message when line is empty
- It is more efficient (faster) to redirect only once.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>samplefile2.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" samplefile.txt') do (
    set "str=%%A"
    set "str=!str:*:=!"
    set "str=!str:day=night!"
    set "str=!str:winter=summer!"
    echo(!str!
  )
)
```

This still has a potential problem. It will corrupt lines that contain `!` when `%%A` is expanded because of the delayed expansion. The trick is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>samplefile2.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" samplefile.txt') do (
    set "str=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "str=!str:*:=!"
    set "str=!str:day=night!"
    set "str=!str:winter=summer!"
    echo(!str!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Or you could forget custom batch entirely and get a much simpler and faster solution using my [JREPL.BAT utility that performs regular expression search and replace on text](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). There are options to specify multiple literal search/replace pairs.

```
jrepl "day winter" "night summer" /t " " /l /i /f sampleFile.txt /o sampleFile2.txt
```

I used the `/I` option to make the search case insensitive. But you can drop that option to make it case sensitive if you prefer. That cannot be done easily using pure batch.